# Do CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() with pre-loaded assembly

Tags: c#

I've defined `ServerImporter` class as following:

```
public class ServerImporter : MarshalByRefObject
{
    ...
}
```

Also I create an instance of `ServerImporter`:

```
AppDomain _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ServerImporterDomain");
var type = typeof (ServerImporter);
ServerImporter si = _domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName) as ServerImporter;
```

It works right. But I've loaded my assembly (with some pre-process) and I want to use it to create an instance of `ServerImporter`:

```
var type = typeof (ServerImporter);
/* My custom Assembly loading (It load an assembly in current domain) */
Assembly assembly = LoadAssemblyFrom(type.Assembly.GetName().Name);
// I want to use this assembly object to do same instance creation
```

I used `assembly.CreateInstance()` but when I cast it, `null` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ServerImporter si = (ServerImporter)Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetType("ServerImporter"));
```

For another AppDomain

```
ServerImporter si = (ServerImporter)Activator.CreateInstance(domain, type.Assembly.FullName, "ServerImporter");
```

Or without using an assembly name you can try

```
ServerImporter si = (ServerImporter)Activator.CreateInstance(domain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(x => x.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(ServerImporter)))[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works; but it doesn't create instance in another domain, am I right?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh Yes you can use it in another domain, i added an example.

Comment: But I cannot use assembly name :( because my assemblies need pre-process to load.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh i added an elaborated example, check if it works or if you can get the type from the assemblies of the appdomain

Comment: Yes, Thank you Sam, I get the type from the assemblies loaded in my custom domain and create an instance by that. Thank your again :)